# Display 3 horizontal divs centre page

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="cont">
   <div class="chatarea">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="message">
            <div class="nick">
               <p>Some Nick</p>
            </div>
            <p>Some Message</p>
            <div class="timestamp"><p>Some Timestamp</p></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#cont {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.chatarea
{
    display: table;
    height : 100%;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:0px;
    width:80%;
}

.nick
{
    width: 400px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

.timestamp
{
    width: 400px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position:absolute; top:0; right:0; height:100%;
}

.message
{
    border-style: solid;
    padding:0 50px 0 140px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

im trying to display 3 divs (left and right smaller than the centre one) in the centre of the page. 80% of the browser width.

i have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zQ9pu/

im having a bit of trouble with it - what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
.chatarea
{
display: table;
height : 100%;
padding-top:50px;
margin:0px auto;
width:80%;
}
```

It works fine !! here is ur new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zQ9pu/2/

Comment: perfect - thank you. the middle div where it has <p>Some Message</p> - the text is not centered. any ideas?

Comment: it works perfectly - but when the height expands the text/content doesnt show?

Answer (score 0):

Contain those divs in a parent block level element which has a specified width and then apply CSS `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on it.